# Kali Linux : Unmet dependency while running upgrade/install commands

Tags: apt, kali-linux, dependencies, dist-upgrade, rolling-release

I am getting unmet dependency error while trying to upgrade. The same problem persists when i try to even install any of the packages mentioned in error.

I am sharing all information that i feel may help.

***Sources.list file info :***

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

***Uname -a command output***

```
Linux debian-me 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.4-1+kali2 (2015-06-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

***apt-get upgrade command output***

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed or
                            libc-dev
 clang-3.5 : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed
 libbluetooth-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed or
                             libc-dev
 libexpat1-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed or
                          libc-dev
 libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed or
                             libc-dev
 libgnuradio-baz : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed
 libpcre3-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed
 libstdc++-4.9-dev : Depends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-5) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6-4.6-dev : Depends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-5) but it is not installed
 libusb-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed or
                       libc-dev
 libxft-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed or
                       libc-dev
 ruby1.8-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed
 ruby1.9.1-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installed or
                       libc-dev
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So far I have tried almost everything that is suggested in various forums (`autoclean`, `dpkg configure`, used `-f`, tried installing the packages) but still the same error persists. Please help I am stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove :

```
deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
```

from your sources.list then:

```
apt update && apt dist-upgrade
```